# Linq to DataSet, Nested Group By?

Tags: linq, datatable, group-by, nested

I'm trying to run a Linq query on a datatable to produce a result, filtered by User and then into Date. I'm following an example of the Group By - Nested on the Linq 101 example page [**here**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

However I wasn't able to get it working. I'm getting a couple of errors. So I was hoping that someone would give me a hand creating the query, or at least help me get on the right track.

This is the current non-working code that I put together from the example.

```
var results =
                 from d in dataTableResults.AsEnumerable()
                 select new 
                    { 
                        d["DIMS User"],
                        DateGroup =
                            from o in d["Entry Date"]
                            group o by o["Entry Date"] into dg
                            select new { "Entry Date" = dg.Key, "DIMS user" = dg}
                    };
```

This is my DataTable Structure: (Date/Time are seperate from ShortDateToString/ShortTimetoString parse)

```
LogData.Columns.Add("System User", typeof(string));
LogData.Columns.Add("Host Name", typeof(string));
LogData.Columns.Add("DIMS User", typeof(string));
LogData.Columns.Add("Entry Details", typeof(string));
LogData.Columns.Add("Asset Name", typeof(string));
LogData.Columns.Add("Entry Date", typeof(string));
LogData.Columns.Add("Entry Time", typeof(string));
```

The errors I'm receiving are:

> 1) Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members
>   must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member
>   access.
>
> 2) Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source
>   type 'object'.  'GroupBy' not found.

Lastly, Thanks for reading my post and Thanks in Advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define property names of anonymous types as strings:

I have defined two classes to get your info together:

```
internal class Entry
{
    public string SystemUser { get; set; }
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string DIMSUser { get; set; }
    public string EntryDetails { get; set; }
    public string AssetName { get; set; }
    public string EntryDate { get; set; }
    public string EntryTime { get; set; }
}

internal class UserEntryPerDateInfo
{
    public string DIMSUser { get; set; }
    public string EntryDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Entry> EntryList { get; set; }
}
```

Here you populate your data:

```
IEnumerable<Entry> dataList = from d in dataTableResults.AsEnumerable()
                              select new Entry
                                {
                                    SystemUser=d["SystemUser"],
                                    HostName=d["Host Name"],
                                    DIMSUser=d["DIMS User"],
                                    EntryDetails=d["Entry Details"],
                                    AssetName=d["Asset Name"],
                                    EntryDate=d["Entry Date"],
                                    EntryTime=d["Entry Time"],
                                };
```

Then you group by date and user and get them in another class:

```
IEnumerable<UserEntryPerDateInfo> result = from a in dataList
                                           group a by new {User = a.DIMSUser, EntryDate = a.EntryDate}
                                           into grouped
                                           select
                                           new UserEntryPerDateInfo
                                           {
                                               DIMSUser = grouped.Key.User,
                                               EntryDate = grouped.Key.EntryDate,
                                               EntryList = grouped
                                           };
```

Comment: Thanks, its much closer to working now. I'm still recieving the error "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'. 'GroupBy' not found". For the piece of code: from o in d["Entry Date"]

Comment: What do you want to get in DateGroup? What do you get from d["EntryDate"] ?

Comment: the Date, they are all from the same data table, I just want it grouped by user and date.

Comment: You want to group them by user or date?

Comment: both, user first then date, is that possible ?

Comment: I updated the code but I didn't select anything. What do you want to get from grouped result?

Comment: select everything, I just need it grouped that way. I'm databinding the results to a WPF chart.

Comment: What will you display in your results? User entry per date?

Comment: yes exactly, that's what I'm looking for, user entries per date